# Непонятен один момент в программе

Tags: java

Только учу java и не понимаю как себя ведет тут переменная e. 
e изначально была равна 0, цикл while не сработал. На втором цикле ей присвоилось значение равное i, i на том цикле стало равно 1, значит e также стала равна 1, потом декрементировалась и е стала равно 0. В состоянии 0 она в начале следующего цикла попала к формуле e=i. Но у нас теперь e=0, а i=2, получается 0=2 - что вообще является непонятным абсурдом и какое значение e спускается дальше вниз по циклу? И как это влияет на работу программы?
В общем буду рад, если объясните вот этот момент с переменными e и i. И как они друг с другом взаимодействуют?

```
public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {

int e;
int result;

for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    result = 1;
    e = i;
    while(e > 0) {
        result *=2;                     
        e--;
    }
    System.out.println(" - 2 в степени " + i + " равно " + result);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получается не 0 = 2, а переменной `e` присваивается значение переменной `i`. Т.е. на второй итераций `е` равно 2.

Вы же все это правильно понимаете парой строк выше:

> На втором цикле ей присвоилось значение равное i, i на том цикле стало
>   равно 1, значит e также стала равна 1

Answer (score 0):

Они не взаимодействуют в обоих направлениях, и сравнивать `e=0, а i=2,` нет никакого смысла

`i` - счётчик цикла, его портить нельзя, поэтому на каждом шаге его **значение копируется** в `e`, и уже с `e` производятся действия